# APT rendered unusable after Wine update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, wine

New Linux user running Kubuntu (22.04.02 LTS), and I have no idea how to progress on this issue. Wine recently released an update to their stable branch, and upon trying to update Wine using Discover, I received an error about a dependency titled `wine-stable-i386` and dpkg not being able to backup a program (the 32-bit version of `cacls.exe`), which didn't exist when I went to go check for it. I believe that, in my attempts to remedy the problem, I have only exacerbated it, to the point where any interface to dpkg (apt, aptitude, etc) fails at installing anything.

Here's how I tried originally combat the problem and unintentionally exacerbated it: I originally copied the x64 version of the program into the `lib` folder for dpkg to detect. That worked, but then it threw the same error for a program that *did* exist. At this point, I removed the 64-bit version of the program and insead of throwing the original error like i expected, it threw the new error again. Next I tried manually reinstalling the dependency over the version I had. Upon that not working, I `rm -rf`ed the folder and tried the reinstall process again. That failed with the error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-stable-i386_8.0.2~jammy-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/opt/wine-stable/lib/wine/i386-windows/aclui.dll.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-stable-i386_8.0.2~jammy-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried creating a dummy file with that exact path, I tried uninstalling as much of Wine that I could then reinstalling everything, and a few other things, but everything I do to try and fix the situation now returns this error.

Any assistance would be *extremely* appreciated.

---

An update:

It seems that this is related to `libwine` in a way. After reading in another post that running more modern versions of software with LTS releases can lead to problems, I tried installing (K)Ubuntu's Wine package (version 6). However, it errored out the same way with `libwine` that it did for `wine-stable-i386`. Even trying `winehq-devel` afterwards yielded the same result.

I don't know if this helps, but I really want to fix this issue.

Comment: "*Wine recently released an update to their stable branch,*" That would only matter if their stable branch is compatible with your release of Ubuntu. If not, then it would really muck up your system.

Comment: @guiverc Added OS details. Is this better?

Comment: I would suggest you do `sudo apt remove wine-stable` and then reinstall it clean.  This wont' mess your WINE prefixes, but it'll remove any leftovers from Wine and then reinstall.

Comment: @ThomasWard-OnStrike Ran the suggested command, and it failed due to missing dependencies. APT then told me to run `--fix-broken install` and upon trying that it errored out the same way I mentioned in my post body.